How do I capture general error text exported by the PIL Image.save function?
I am using PIL to convert (mostly) TIFF files to other formats (currently PDF).  For the most part this is working fine, but occasionally due to corrupted images the save_handler will throw messages similar to these:
Fax4Decode: Uncompressed data (not supported) at line 1333 of strip 0 (x 770).
Fax4Decode: Uncompressed data (not supported) at line 1334 of strip 0 (x 0).
Fax4Decode: Uncompressed data (not supported) at line 1557 of strip 0 (x 0).
Fax4Decode: Bad code word at line 1613 of strip 0 (x 1694).
Fax4Decode: Bad code word at line 1654 of strip 0 (x 4).

It is being generated at this line where 'images' is a list of open files using Image.open()
images[0].save(pf_path, "PDF", resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
This looks to be coming from an underlying pyd library and is understandable since some images could be corrupt, but I need to be able to try, except these in order to find which items are throwing these warnings.
I have tried using the warnings module as well as redirecting stdout and stderr to try and catch these messages but neither have worked.
